# How to Define Multiple List Tables in a Single Submenu

Tags: plugins, wp-list-table

I am coding a plugin using WP_List_Table ([The source code I am using](https://github.com/w3guy/WP_List_Table-Class-Plugin-Example).). The plugin I coded performs the function of adding a submenu to another plugin in the admin panel. A simple one-file plugin. I defined 1 table in the submenu. So far, no problem.

In the plugin, I want to define another table in the same submenu. Even if I define "different classes" in the same file, the conflict occurs. I couldn't find how to fix this problem. If anyone has a recommendation, I'd be glad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You don't.**

`WP_List_Table` and the following features were all built on the assumption of there only being a single table on the page:

- choosing columns via screen options
- pagination
- column sorting
- search/filtering
- bulk actions

At best, you could use the code from the official developer docs to print a second table, but then you'll run into all the broken functionality, or other problems. E.g. when moving to page 2, all tables move to page 2, or conflicting columns.

As an aside, there's no such thing as defining a table in a sub-menu. A sub-menu defines a page which is just a function that gets called. If you use that function to display a table, or two tables or no tables, that's entirely up to you and unrelated to the sub menu.

Instead, have you considered custom post types and post meta/custom fields? Doing it this way means you've got to build and design your tables from scratch and then rebuild everything WordPress does for you, e.g. edit screens, REST API, frontend templates, etc etc

Comment: Also, your `Customers_List` class is hardcoded to display specific things, if you wanted a second customer list you'd have to create a second class to display something different anyway, assuming it would all work anyway, you'd still have all the issues I outlined in my answer such as clashing filters and pagination

Comment: I thought so, too. Thanks for the explanation.